# Cannot get the 'POST' to change into result page with Flask web application

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using the FLASK python application to create a website online. I have used nicepage.com to create a HTML base and I have gotten it to work in the flask app. The problem is that I cannot get the submit button for a textarea to forward me to another html page.

The HTML code about the textarea:

```
<section class="u-align-left u-clearfix u-image u-shading u-section-2" src="" data-image-width="1280" data-image-height="850" id="sec-32aa">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <h1 class="u-text u-text-default u-title u-text-1">Try it Yourself</h1>
        <p class="u-large-text u-text u-text-variant u-text-2">Write or paste your prefered text below!<br>WARNING: Do not provide real or actual personal.&nbsp;
        </p>
        <div class="u-form u-form-1">
          <form action="{{ url_for('submit') }}" method="post" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-13 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" style="padding: 10px;">
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-message">
              <label  class="u-label">Text</label>
              <textarea id="text_form" name="text_form" placeholder="​Enter your prefered text... " rows="9" cols="50"   class="u-border-4 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br>
            </div>
            <div class="u-align-left u-form-group u-form-submit">
              <a href="#" class="u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style">Submit</a>
              <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section
```

Where I want it to appear:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Python project</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/css_venv.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Personal data testing app</h1>
        <p>{{ var|safe }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import request
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("Home.html")

@app.route("/result")
def result():
    return render_template("Result.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("About.html")

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("Home.html")

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    text = request.form['text_form']
    result=text
    csvfile=pd.read_csv("matrikkel_test.csv")
 
    address = address3(text)
    if address:
        for i in address:
            result = result.replace(i,'<mark style="color: red;">'+i+"</mark>")
            '''
    return render_template("index2.html",var=result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

So the question again is. Why does it not want to change webpage when I hit the submit button? Can it be that the nicepage.com have locked so I cannot through code send to another webpage?

I am quite new with coding but have gained a ok understanding of the html in this page. I hope the fault doesn't reside in the .JS code they provide.

The message I get from the gcloud platform: 127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2022 20:00:49] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: In this code, everything after the three quote marks `'''` is treated as a string, not as code.

Answer (score -1):

Just as [@john Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) mentioned the triple quotes `'''`  at the end of your `submit()` endpoint comments out the line of code responsible for rendering a new template. So you should remove those and it should work.

Comment: Ah yes thank you for answer. But those quotes were just a slipup in my editing it here. They are not visible in the code. Thank you for the answer though.